# Continuous, Differentiable Function with Certain Properties

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, integers

Let $f(n,x)$ be a continuous, differentiable function that the number of terms does not depend on $n$ (aka $\sum$, $\prod$, etc.) $f(n,x)=0$ only when $n/x$ is an integer ($x$ need not to be an integer). These properties only have to hold for $-n\leq x \leq n$ What is an example of such $f(n,x)$?

Comment: You can't.  A polynomial of degree $d$ (over any field) has at most $d$ zeroes.  Your function would need infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: What is $3.7$ modulo $2$?

Comment: @EthanBolker $1.7$

Comment: You must not replace a question with one that is totally different. You can delete this question, and post a new one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I actually can't post a new question (something about asking too many questions)

Comment: Then I guess you just have to play by the rules, and work for the question ban to be lifted. This might help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans